# Как выводить меню. Структура mvc .php

Tags: php, mvc

Как  вывести категории новостей в шапку меню, так чтобы не копипастить код каждый раз при добавлении нового action.  нужно чтобы меню всегда было видно .

Comment: ну так ясно же разрабатывать систему layout'ов

Comment: а можно поподробнее как ето реализуется. пример

Comment: берется какой-нибудь smarty или twig и с ними работается.

Comment: @Антон Пивоваров даже не систему лаяаутов, а систему виджетов. Во фреймворках (Yii, Zend, ..) это так или иначе поддерживается. Система виджетов - это когда страницу можно лепить из разных независимых блоков-кусков - виджетов. При этом каждый виджет будет являться отдельным MCA (module-controller-action) . Твоё меню в контексте такой системы - тоже виджет.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TemplateEngine {
    ...
    $path="var/www/htmldoc/";
    public function renderPage($page) {
        echo $this->makeElement("header");
        echo $this->makeElement($page);
        echo $this->makeElement("footer");
    }

    public function makeElement($elementName) {
        return file_get_contents($this->path.$elementName.".html";)
    }
    ...
}
```

Это, наверно, самый простой способ.
Файлы соответственно должны лежать по направлению переменной $path.
И называться, например, "header.html".
Также можно использовать twig (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/), в котором уже это и не только хорошо реализовано.

Пример использования.
Контроллер:

```
<?php
    //simpleController.php
    public function someAction() {
        $template = new TemplateEngine();
        $template->renderPage("index");
    }
?>
```

Шапка (header.html):

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
```

Сама страница (index.html):

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Подвал (footer.html):

```
<body></html>
```

Comment: Система лейаутов у меня есть. Я создам например IndexController в нем метод index в нем получю из бази список категорий и определю их в переменную data['category'] дальше вызову метод рендер . вот и у меня ето меню будет видно только в http://Index/index а вот например в  http://Index/contact  его уже видно не будет. В етом и проблема.

Comment: Просто используйте $template->renderPage("contact"). И так для любой нужной страницы.

Comment: но список категорий  data['category'] я в нем не получю потому что он в методе index

Comment: Вы можете его получать в самом методе renderPage() - для всех страниц, создающихся с его помощью. В этом и суть MVC, разделение модели, контроллера и представления. Также Вы можете его получать прямо в header.html путем php вставок, что не очень рекомендуется делать.